# d3 cloud layout - show all tags

Tags: javascript, d3.js, word-cloud

**[background]**
currently I'm working on a little web project for data visualization and I want to use create a tagcloud or wordcloud with cloud layout of the javascript d3 framework ([d3 cloud layout](http://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/#http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jasondavies.com%2Fwordtree%2Fcat-in-the-hat.txt)).

I've built some examples that almost satisfy my requirements. The only thing that doesn't work is, that some words/tags aren't displayed in my tag cloud. 
As far as I understand the placing algorithm for the tags, this comes because the algorithm finds no suitable place to position all tags without overlaying other tags.

**My question:** How can I display all available tags and is there a setting in the framework to do this?
I'm rather new to javascript so I had quite a hard time to understand the whole cloud layout and the positioning algorithm to find a way to achieve my goal.

Comment: There's no flag you can set to have it do this. You would need to modify the source.

Comment: modify the source in what way? I thougt about downscaling all tags to an appropriate size, to increase the possibility for the placing algorithm to position all tags. But even though there's no guarantee all tags of the source are displayed

Comment: This is likely to be quite a major change. I'm not familiar with the source, so I can't really give you a starting point, sorry.

Comment: @RichardJ. I'm facing the same problem. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: The solution #3 here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27672989/dynamically-sized-word-cloud-using-d3-cloud did the job in my application.