# Dynamically sized word-cloud using d3-cloud

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-cloud

I am creating a wordcloud by modifying code from : https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud. I can change the size by modifying w & h but I want to scale the word cloud as the browser window changes. What would be the best method to achieve this?

Code also posted at http://plnkr.co/edit/AZIi1gFuq1Vdt06VIETn?p=preview

```
<script>

 myArray = [{"text":"First","size":15},{"text":"Not","size":29},{"text":"Bird","size":80},    {"text":"Hello","size":40},{"text":"Word","size":76},{"text":"Marketplaces","size":75}]
var fillColor = d3.scale.category20b();
var w = 400, // if you modify this also modify .append("g") .attr -- as half of this
  h = 600;

d3.layout.cloud().size([w, h])
  .words(myArray) // from list.js
  .padding(5)
  .rotate(0)      
  .font("Impact")
  .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
  .on("end", drawCloud)
  .start();

function drawCloud(words) {
d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + w/2 + "," + h/2 + ")")
  .selectAll("text")
    .data(words)
    .enter().append("text")
    .style("font-size", function(d) { return (d.size) + "px"; })
    .style("font-family", "Impact")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fillColor(i); })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
          return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
        }
    )
  .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution # 1:**

On line 37:

```
.style("font-size", function(d) { return (d.size) + "px"; })
```

Replace

```
.style("font-size", function(d) { return (d.size/3) + "vh"; }) // "d.size/3" is an assumption use your appropriate relative width or height.
```

Instead of using `px` use `vw` which is view port width. It is a css3 feature that will resize the text according to the viewport. However, you will need to adjust the real width and height properly.

Try reading this article: http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

**Solution # 2:**

On line 37:

```
    .style("font-size", function(d) { return (d.size) + "px"; })
```

Use

```
   .attr("class", nameOfClass) // use class names here like 'big-font', 'med-font', 'small-font'
```

and in the CSS define the styles using media queries, the classes will be assigned depending upon the d.size in the condition so do it like if (d.size > 10) nameOfClass = "big-font" etc.

Instead of giving words width and height using JS, allocate classes to them using media queries breakpoints.

Read : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

I recommend solution 2 as i believe `vw` and `vh` is not supported by all the browsers. http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units. There are some issues reported related to that.

Comment: I would like to change the window size not the size of the font, which is currently described by var w = 400, 
  h = 600;

Answer (score 3):

**Solution # 3:**

To calculate the font-size, you have to create this scale:

```
var fontSizeScale = d3.scale.pow().exponent(5).domain([0,1]).range([ minFont, maxFont]);
```

and call it in `fontSize` function:

```
var maxSize = d3.max(that.data, function (d) {return d.size;});

 .fontSize(function (d) {
        return fontSizeScale(d.size/maxSize);
      })
```

---

To fit the bounds to your screen/div:

in the `.on("end", drawCloud)` function, call this function:

```
function zoomToFitBounds() {

      var X0 = d3.min( words, function (d) {
        return d.x - (d.width/2);
      }),
        X1 = d3.max( words, function (d) {
          return d.x + (d.width/2);
        });

      var Y0 = d3.min( words, function (d) {
          return d.y - (d.height/2);
        }),
        Y1 = d3.max( words, function (d) {
          return d.y + (d.height/2);
        });

      var scaleX = (X1 - X0) / (width);
      var scaleY = (Y1 - Y0) / (height);

      var scale = 1 / Math.max(scaleX, scaleY);

      var translateX = Math.abs(X0) * scale;
      var translateY = Math.abs(Y0) * scale;

      cloud.attr("transform", "translate(" +
        translateX + "," + translateY + ")" +
        " scale(" + scale + ")");
}
```